# fromPathPiece has type ()

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm using multiple forms at once on my page, and when the user clicks 'update' I need to figure out which record goes with the form data that was returned.

Right now I'm trying to do this with toPathPiece/fromPathPiece, and storing the key in a hidden Text field on the form.

The text is returned ok, so I get back something like "3".  But I get this error when I try to do a replace using the key:

```
Handler/Song.hs:137:15:
    Couldn't match type ‘()’ with ‘Key SongChord’
    Expected type: HandlerT App IO (Key SongChord)
      Actual type: HandlerT App IO ()
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: runDB $ replace sc_id sc
    In the expression: do { runDB $ replace sc_id sc }
    In a case alternative:
        Just sc_id -> do { runDB $ replace sc_id sc }
```

And here's the code that has the problem:

```
(_, _, Just _) -> do
  chordz <- runDB $ selectList [SongChordSong ==. sid] [Asc SongChordSeqnum]
  chordroots <- runDB $ selectList [] []
  notesets <- runDB $ selectList [] [] 
  let rootz = map (\(Entity crid cr) -> (chordRootName cr, crid)) chordroots
      nsetz = map (\(Entity nsid ns) -> (noteSetName ns, nsid)) notesets 
  ((res, widget),enctype) <- 
    runFormPost $ scfForm Nothing sid (length chordz) rootz nsetz 
  case res of 
    FormSuccess scf -> do
      -- fromScf takes the form datatype and returns (Text,SongChord)
      let (mbsctext, sc) = fromScf scf
          mbscid = fromPathPiece mbsctext :: Maybe (Key SongChord)
      sck <- case mbscid of 
        Nothing -> do 
          runDB $ insert sc
        Just sc_id -> do
          -- runDB $ insert sc
          -- here's the problem!
          runDB $ replace sc_id sc 
      defaultLayout $ [whamlet|
        <h1> #{show mbscid}
        <br> #{show sck}
        <br> #{show scf}
        |]
```

What's wierd is if I comment out the replace (and uncomment the insert) then it compiles and runs, and the resulting web page has mbscid on it, looking like it was a valid key. This is the text from the page in this case:

```
Just (SongChordKey {unSongChordKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 2}})

SongChordKey {unSongChordKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 16}}

Scf {song = SongKey {unSongKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 1}}, chordroot = ChordRootKey {unChordRootKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 9}}, noteset = NoteSetKey {unNoteSetKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 2}}, seqnum = 15, duration = 202, scid = "2"}
Insert copyright statement here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the types for `insert` and `replace` (ignoring the constraints for brevity):

```
insert :: val -> m (Key val)
replace :: Key val -> val -> m ()
```

Branches of a `case` expression have to have the same type. (Otherwise `sck`'s type would be different depending on which branch is taken.) Because your `insert` and `replace` calls are the last expressions in their respective branches, their types have to match. Since the `Key val` and `()` in their types are different, you're getting that error.

You can get the `replace` branch to have the right type by returning the key:

```
Just sc_id -> do
    runDB $ replace sc_id sc
    return sc_id
```

Comment: and, was able to dispense with the toPathPiece/fromPathPiece and just put the key in the hidden field directly.